# Problema para agregar formulario a db - consultas preparadas

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

he estado todo el día con esto y no he logrado encontrar el problema.

Estoy haciendo un formulario con bootstrap en el cual debe registrarse algunos datos a una DB Mysql mediante funciones de Js, no se porque estoy viendo en la consola errores de "undefined index" como si no encontrara algún nombre del formulario pero si están todos, alguien que pueda ayudarme con esto, se lo agradecería mucho!

Formulario:

```
<form id="formparallenar">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="disabledSelect">Nombre:</label>
                                <select id="disabledSelect" class="form-control">
                                    <option name="nombre">Nombre disabled</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div>
                            Fecha: 
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Hora: 
                            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="hora" placeholder="Hora">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Entidad: 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="entidad" placeholder="Cual es el nombre de la entidad?">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Municipio: 
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="municipio">
                                <option selected="true" class="disabled" disabled>Seleccionar Municipio</option>
                                <option>opción número 1</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="tiempo1">Cantidad:</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tiempo1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg">
                                    <label for="tiempo2">Tiempo:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="tiempo2">
                                        <option selected="true" disabled>Seleccionar...</option>
                                        <option>Días</option>
                                        <option>Horas</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" name="checkboxes">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Ingresos</label>
                                <br />
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Creditos</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Otro Motivo: 
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Textocualquiera?" name="otromot">
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="funcionparaelboton()"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Registrar</button>
                        </form>
```

Y esta es la función en js:

```
function funcionparaelboton(){


    if ($('#fecha').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado la fecha!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#hora').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado la hora!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#entidad').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado el nombre de la entidad!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#municipio').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado el nombre!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#tiempo1').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado la cantidad!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#tiempo2').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha agregado el tiempo!");
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#checkboxes').val()==""){
        swal("No se ha seleccionado checkbox!");
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:$('#formparallenar').serialize(),
        url:"ruta/delarchivo/paraagregardatos.php",
        success:function(r){
            //console.log(r); <-Con esto es que vi los errores undefined
            if(r==1){
                $('#formparallenar')[0].reset();
                mostrarDatos();
                swal("OK","Registrado con exito!","success");
            }else{
                swal("Falta algo","No se ha podido registrar, faltan datos.","error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Y este es el archivo que estoy usando donde está la conexión y los bind param

```
include "../../basedd/archivoconexion.php";
$conexion=conexion();

$registrar=array(
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['nombre'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['fecha'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['hora'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['entidad'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['municipio'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['tiempo1'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['tiempo2'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['checkboxes'])),
$conexion->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['otromot']))
);

$sql="INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (nombre,fecha,hora,entidad,municipio,tiempo1,tiempo2,checkboxes,otromot) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$query=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('sssssssss',$datos[0],$datos[1],$datos[2],$datos[3],$datos[4],$datos[5],$datos[6],$datos[7],$datos[8]);

echo $query->execute();

$query->close();
```

Comment: Lo que veo es que creas un array ` $registrar=array( ... ` , pero luego en el binding estas usando ` $datos[]`

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comenta @Alex, es mucho más claro hacer binding con variables por separado que usar un array. Además, si usas consultas preparadas, no necesitas ni `real_escape_string` y `htmlentities`. Puedes recuperar cada dato en variables y usarlas para el binding. Para evitar los *undefined index*  puedes usar un ternario que verifique con `empty` si cada dato está, haciendo asignación al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de lo que te comenta @Alex, es mucho más claro hacer binding con variables por separado que usar un array. Además, si usas consultas preparadas, no necesitas ni `real_escape_string` y `htmlentities`. Puedes recuperar cada dato en variables y usarlas para el binding. Para evitar los *undefined index*  puedes usar un ternario que verifique con `empty` si cada dato está, haciendo asignación al mismo tiempo.

Podrías escribir el código así sin riesgo ninguno:

```
include "../../basedd/archivoconexion.php";
$conexion=conexion();
$nombre     =!empty($_POST['nombre'])      ? $_POST['nombre']     : NULL;
$fecha      =!empty($_POST['fecha'])       ? $_POST['fecha']      : NULL;
$hora       =!empty($_POST['hora'])        ? $_POST['hora']       : NULL;
$entidad    =!empty($_POST['entidad'])     ? $_POST['entidad']    : NULL;
$municipio  =!empty($_POST['municipio'])   ? $_POST['municipio']  : NULL;
$tiempo1    =!empty($_POST['tiempo1'])     ? $_POST['tiempo1']    : NULL;
$tiempo2    =!empty($_POST['tiempo2'])     ? $_POST['tiempo2']    : NULL;
$checkboxes =!empty($_POST['checkboxes'])  ? $_POST['checkboxes'] : NULL;
$otromot    =!empty($_POST['otromot'])     ? $_POST['otromot']    : NULL;


$sql="INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (nombre,fecha,hora,entidad,municipio,tiempo1,tiempo2,checkboxes,otromot) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

if ($query=$conexion->prepare($sql)) {
    $query->bind_param('sssssssss',$nombre,$fecha,$hora,$entidad,$municipio,$tiempo1,$tiempo2,$checkboxes,$otromot);
    if($query->execute()) {
        $msg= sprintf("Se insertaron %d filas",$conexion-> affected_rows);
        $query->close();
    } else {
        $msg="Error en la inserción";
    }
} else {
    $msg="Error preparando la consulta";
}
echo $msg;
```

Verás que he establecido controles que faltaban en el código. La preparación puede fallar, no necesariamente una consulta insertará por ser del tipo `INSERT INTO`. Un fallo común en este tipo de consultas es cuando se violan restricciones que pueda tener la tabla. No puedes por tanto determinar que una consulta funcionó con un simple `echo` sobre el `execute.

En la forma de recuperar las variables con el ternario, puedes hacer un control de aquellos datos que son obligatorios, que tienen la restricción `NOT NULL` en la tabla, emitiendo un mensaje de error al cliente en vez de intentar una consulta que será fallida. Como no conozco ese dato no he puesto nada. Supongamos que `$nombre` y `$fecha` son obligatorios, entonces ese sería el primer control antes de intentar insertar:

```
if ($nombre && $fecha) {
    //... todo el código de insertar
} else {
    $msg="Hay campos obligatorios sin llenar";
}
echo $msg;
```

**PD:**

Hay una forma de simplificar los `bind_param`, para pasarlos como array, mediante el uso de [Listas de argumentos de longitud variable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).